# ruby pass var from view(link_to) to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how can I do it? This code does not work:

```
<% Dir.entries(Pathname.new("/Cd") + params[:project_id] + Pathname.new("art"))[2..-1].each do |file_name| %>
<li><%= link_to file_name, {:action => 'download' } :params=> {:file_name => path} %></li>
<% end %>


def download 
@path = :params(path)
    send_file(path)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's `params[:path]`, not `:params(path)`, so your `download` method should look like this:

```
def download
  @path = params[:path]
  send_file(@path)
end
```

Secondly, your [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) is wrong. It should look something like this:

```
<%= link_to file_name, { :action => 'download', :path => file_name } %>
```

By the way, what you're doing is very unsafe. A user can send any path to the `download` method, potentially allowing them to download *any* file on your system.

Comment: Thanks, its work. This plugin will work in the local network. I do not need security

Comment: Can you tell me how to generate link. my code does not work: send_file("/cd/" + path)